# Que signifient l'inapplication et l'intérêt dans les écrits du dix-huitième siècle ?

Tags: sens, littérature

Dans ses Mémoires, le cardinal de Retz dépeint Anne d'Autriche, Reine de France et mère de Louis XIV qui l'a congédié de la cours, avec une méchanceté assassine mais aurtout un vocabulaire plus tellement utilisé avec le même sens.

Je souhaitais savoir ce que signifiait la phrase suivante :

> La Reine avait (...) plus d'*inapplication à l'argent* que de libéralité, plus de libéralité que
> d'*intérêt*, plus d'intérêt que de désintéressement, plus d'attachement
> que de passion, plus de dureté que de fierté, (...) plus d'opiniâtreté que de fermeté

J'ai mis en italique les mots dont je ne comprenais pas le sens dans la phrase.

Voici le passage entier :

> La Reine avait, plus que personne que j'aie jamais vu, de cette sorte
> d'esprit qui lui était nécessaire pour ne pas paraître sotte à ceux
> qui ne la connaissaient pas. Elle avait plus d'aigreur que de hauteur,
> plus de hauteur que de grandeur, plus de manières que de fond, plus
> d'inapplication à l'argent que de libéralité, plus de libéralité que
> d'intérêt, plus d'intérêt que de désintéressement, plus d'attachement
> que de passion, plus de dureté que de fierté, plus de mémoire des
> injures que des bienfaits, plus d'intention de piété que de piété,
> plus d'opiniâtreté que de fermeté, et plus d'incapacité que de tout ce
> que dessus.
>
> Mémoire, cardinal de Retz, 1717

Answer (score 2):

Je vais essayer, mais cette réponse est soumise à validation par des *vrais* spécialistes de cet auteur et de cette période. ;)

#### Inapplication

> plus d'inapplication à l'argent que de libéralité

On dirait le [sens B que donne le TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inapplication) : désintérêt (pour la chose financière).

#### Intérêt

> plus de libéralité que d'intérêt

`intérêt` a peut-être plus changé de sens depuis le XVIIème s. [Le Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française de 1694](https://books.google.fr/books?id=jEQ8AAAAMAAJ&pg=PP7#v=onepage&q=int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt&f=false) donne, pour `intéresser` : 'Émouvoir, toucher de quelque passion'. 'Plus de libéralité que d'intérêt' pourrait vouloir dire que la reine est plus généreuse par nature (**edit** : ou par souci des apparences) que par un vrai intérêt pour autrui.

> plus d'intérêt que de désintéressement

On dirait [un genre de jeu de mots](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Polyptote) entre deux sens d'`intéresser` : 1/ intérêt-altruisme et 2/ intérêt-intéressement. Pour moi, le premier `intérêt` renvoie au sens précédent, c'est-à-dire intérêt pour autrui, et le second veut dire abnégation (**edit** : plutôt, c'est `désintéressement` veut dire abnégation, négligence de ses propres intérêts).

En français moderne, je paraphraserais ainsi :

> la reine était plus désintéressée par l'argent que réellement généreuse,
>   elle était plus généreuse que sincèrement altruiste, et son altruisme n'était guère désintéressé.

Pas aussi clair et concis que chez [JF](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_Paul_de_Gondi), vous en conviendrez :)

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse éclairant les propos de Jeff, j'attends l'aval de vrais spécialistes pour vous octroyer une gourmande récompense en points et notoriété dans le royaume de Stackexchange